# Why is image size and the memory required to display it different?

Tags: memory, memory-usage

I learned from a [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33864168/getting-this-exception-which-forces-the-android-app-to-crash-on-start/33864558#33864558) that the memory required to display an image and the image size is equal to

```
4 * image dimensions
```

I have some 800x800 images and I see that its size is about a hundred KB, which I think is quite small. But according to the formula above, it needs more than 2MB to display it!

The SO post says that because the bitmap is using ARGB colors, each pixel requires 4 bytes of storage space. So that's why the formula is *4* * image dimensions. But I see that only 100KB of space is required to store the image!

Does the computer use a different method to store the image? Does 1 pixel still needs 4B to be stored? How is this happening?

Comment: And _where_ do you see that its size is about a hundred kB?

Comment: In its properties window

Comment: You mean, on disk?

Comment: It's a fact that the answer you quote gives a bad recommendation. RGB888 is you first choice if you don't need transparency, not ARGB. Especially on a mobile device. It saves 25% memory as compared to ARGB and also, if you stack Android `View`s, adding transparency will slow down things.

Answer (score 3):

**[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.de/)** can help to quickly view the used memory:
(see the memory calculation)
[image]

**WIDTH** x **HEIGHT** x **(BITS PER PIXEL)** = memory needed to load the full image

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Your image is compressed (e.g. with `jpeg` or `png`). If you'd store the image in an uncompressed format (`tiff` without `zip` compression) you would get that size on disk, too.

Comment: The Q asks how this is happening.

Comment: @ClassStacker I know. And my answer is `with compression`

Comment: Yess... JPEG/JPG and PNG's use lossy compression methods

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like PNGs use lossy compression methods? Who told you this nonsense?

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like jpeg uses a lossy compression. PNG is lossless

Comment: Well not a complete nonsense as PNG **supports lossless compression** but it is lossless **position-wise, not necessarily color-wise**

Comment: @ClassStacker you also might want to read [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/203979/is-the-png-format-lossless-since-it-has-a-compression-parameter/)

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like What are you trying to say? How does the link contribute to the discussion? And what is a compression which is lossless position-wise, but not colour-wise?

Answer (score 2):

The memory required to store an image can be less than the memory required to display it. For example, if the image is an 80x80 green rectangle, you can store it as the equivalent of "80 by 80 green rectangle". But to display it, you need 1600 green dots, each of which is going to take up some space.

Comment: You mean to store an 80x80 square it just needs to store one pixel of green and some metadata saying it's 80x80?

Comment: @Sweeper It *can* do that to store it. But it can't do that to display it.